Interpreting differences between confidence intervals with and without adjustment for clustering. Should those from adjustment be wider?
I am trying to interpret an article involving data from a cluster randomised trial, where the confidence intervals for effect sizes are said to have been adjusted 'using the standard errors of the regression co-efficient and transformed into an effect size to produce the upper and lower bounds of the effect size' Compared with the more usual way of computing CIs for ESs this results in much narrower confidence intervals, and more statistically significant results. My confusion arises because if this measure is supposed to correct CSBias, then surly it should result in wider confidence intervals given the usual direction of CSBias. That apart, how does one resolve discrepancies between confidence intervals computed in different ways ?

The key is whether the standard error for the regression coefficient accounted for clustering.

Clustered SEs can be smaller if there is negative correlation between the errors within clusters. Take a look at this question for details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394055/clustered-standard-errors-why-are-se-smaller-or-bigger-than-ols-depending-on-c/394330?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C28.4140#394330.
